# Does rewriting a library in another language allow escaping GPL?

Tags: gpl

Given a library A, which is written in C and licensed under GPLv2, and lib B, which is written in Rust and compatible with the API/specs of lib A but the devs have read through the code of lib A, can lib B be relicensed under the MIT license?

Assuming the above situation again but the devs have not read through the source code (black box engineering), does the GPL still apply?